# remove track number from start of song name iTunes

Tags: macos, itunes, mojave, music

I just imported my own folder of audio files into iTunes.

Now every song is prepended with a track number, 01, 02, ... 18, etc.

How do I remove these? Other albums don't have this (despite the files in `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music` having the prepended numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The track name is taken from the metadata (or, if there isn't any, from the filename) of the tracks during import. So if after the import you end up with the track number in the title this was already encoded in the file itself.

To remove, either edit each title after the import or pick an appropriate script from [Doug's AppleScripts for iTunes](https://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/scripts09.php).